# ensure that an iterator dereferences to a certain type

Tags: c++

I have to implement a function that takes an iterator. The iterator must dereference to a certain type, say int:

```
template<typename iter>
  void f(iter i) {
  // do something here ...
  int t = *i;
  // do something here ...
}
```

The problem with this code is that if a user calls the function like this

```
vector<string> v;
v.push_back("aaa");
f(v.begin());
```

he will see an error pointing to some place in my code, not in his code (which will be confusing to him). I want the error to be in user's code to ease debugging.

Comment: I like Luther Blissett's solution for its natural output (when a user sees "no matching function..." he starts checking the type of the arguments and does not assume that there is a bug in my function).

Also, GMan's solution is very good, because it explicitly tells what the problem is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GMan already pointed to a method to solve this via compile time assertions. There is another  way to do this, which I prefer (it's my favorite C++ technique). You can put constraints on function arguments in a way that the function is **ignored** for overload resolution if the constraints don't fit. This is quite terrific, because you can fine tune your function overloads to arbitrary conditions. Here's how:

```
#include <boost/utility.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>
#include <vector>


template<typename Iter> typename
boost::enable_if<
    boost::is_same<typename Iter::value_type,int>,
void>::type
foo(Iter it) { }

int main() {    
    std::vector<int> v; // this is OK
    foo(v.begin());
    std::vector<double> v2; // this is an error
    foo(v2.begin()); }
```

If you compile this, you will get

```
b.cc: In function 'int main()':
b.cc:19:16: error: no matching function for call to 'foo(std::vector<double>::iterator)'
```

This is because the compiler would consider foo() only, if it's argument has a value_type type inside, which is 'int' (This is what the enable_if part means). The second call of foo() can't satisfy this constraint.

enable_if is mentioned a couple of times in SO, just search for it: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=enable_if

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this:

```
#include <boost/type_traits/is_convertible.hpp>
#include <boost/typeof/typeof.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/assert.hpp>

template <typename Iter>
void foo(Iter pIter)
{
    BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG(
        (boost::is_convertible<BOOST_TYPEOF(*pIter), int>::value),
        DEREFERENCED_ITERATOR_MUST_BE_CONVERTIBLE_TO_INT,
        (int));

    // ...
}

#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main(void)
{
    std::vector<std::string> v(5);

    foo(v.begin());
}
```

Which makes the message quite visible:

> error C2664: 'boost::mpl::assertion_failed' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'boost::mpl::failed ************(__thiscall foo::DEREFERENCED_ITERATOR_MUST_BE_CONVERTIBLE_TO_INT::* ***********)(int)' to 'boost::mpl::assert::type'

But like James says, most compilers give plenty of information to find out what happened anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Given the code in question, most compilers will refer to the point of instantiation in the diagnostic message.  For the following, line 16 is the line `f(v.begin());`.

Microsoft Visual C++ reports:

```
> c:\example\main.cpp(16) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void f<std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>>(iter)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Myvec=std::_Vector_val<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>,
1>              iter=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>>
1>          ]
```

g++ reports:

```
main.cpp:16:   instantiated from here
```

Intel C++ Compiler and Comeau both report:

```
detected during instantiation of
                "void f(iter) [with iter=std::string *]" at line 16
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a [constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a174071k.aspx) on the generic type.

Comment: That's not C++, but a variant of it. (Microsoft wouldn't let you know that from reading the page, though.)

Comment: @GMan:  Actually they sort of do; that page is in the section called "Language Features for Targeting the CLR"

Comment: @James: Okay, so maybe I'm just dumb, but still... :P

Comment: @GMan:  If you are dumb, I don't want to know where that leaves the rest of us.  :-)